# Who set the trap for Robert Neville?

Tags: movie, i-am-legend

About two third of the way through the movie the following takes place:

> Robert Neville is driving around and sees that Fred the Mannequin is not outside the video rental shop. When he approaches it he springs a trap and strings him up and knocks him unconscious.

I always thought it was a trap setup by the Dark Seekers. However, the accepted answer on this question on [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/how-did-fred-mannequin-move-outside-the-store) seems to think the trap was set by Robert himself.

Fred is previously seen outside of the video store entrance, so he is available for anyone to just up and take.

So who set the trap?

Comment: I absolutely disagree with the accepted answer on that Movies.SE question. It was the other character mentioned, all the evidence points to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It appears that the seekers were learning, and still expressed some
>  emotion by that time. The alpha also leads his pack to Neville's house
>  in the end, showing that they can function as a primitive unit.

I was under the impression that the Seeker (or just the Alpha Seeker) watched Neville's movements after he captured the female seeker. Eventually they copied the trap he used and left behind, with Fred as bait.

Comment: Any reason for the spoiler formatting ?

Comment: Not a whole lot to be honest, I just marked the first paragraph because it deals with the very end of the movie. The unmarked part talks about the trap which was mentioned in the unspoilered text of the question.